# VF page does not display value that of variable that Controller debug log shows

Tags: visualforce, logging

I have been tasked with adding features to a large existing SF codebase. One of the features I am adding requires that a particular page be saved as a PDF. 
The newly generated PDF page displays properly except for one very strange problem: When the PDF page is generated it displays a previously assigned value for the Country Codes in the Billing and Shipping Addresses (all other values are correct). I have debug statements in place to show the Country Code values immediately before generating the PDF and the debug logs show the correct value. I am absolutely out of ideas why this could be.

Below is my `makePDF()` method. You can see where I log the values for `application.Shipping_Country__c` & `application.Billing_Country__c` which are the problem values:

```
    public void makePDF() {

        // THESE DEBUG STATEMENTS LOG THE CORRECT/EXPECTED VALUE
        System.debug('--> Start makePDF()');
        System.debug('Shipping_Country__c before PDF: "' + application.Shipping_Country__c +'"');
        System.debug('Billing_Country__c  before PDF: "' + application.Billing_Country__c +'"');
        System.debug('ShippingCountryName before PDF: "' + ShippingCountryName +'"');
        System.debug('BillingCountryName  before PDF: "' + BillingCountryName +'"');
        System.debug('Shipping_Country_PDF__c before PDF: "' + application.Shipping_Country_PDF__c +'"');
        System.debug('Billing_Country_PDF__c before PDF: "' + application.Billing_Country_PDF__c +'"');

        // PDF GENERATION STARTS HERE BUT THE GENERATED PAGE USES AN OLD VALUE
        PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/MembershipApplicationPDF');
        Blob body;

        try {
            System.debug('Performing try pdf.getContentAsPdf()');
            body = pdf.getContentAsPdf();
        } catch (VisualforceException e) {
            System.debug('PDF Generation Error: ' + e);
            body = Blob.valueOf('Error : ' + e);
        }

        // ANYTHING BELOW THIS I SUSPECT ISN'T PART OF MY ISSUE BUT INCLUDED FOR COMPLETENESS.
        Id memDocId = null;
        for(Account accIt : [SELECT Id, Name, (Select Id, OwnerId, Name, Membership_Document__c, Document_Type__c From Membership_Documents__r) FROM Account WHERE Id=:AccountId]){
            for(Membership_Document__c md : accIt.Membership_Documents__r) {
                if (md.Document_Type__c == 'Membership Agreement') {  // If the related list already contains a Membership Agreement container then assign that.
                    memDocId = md.Id;
                }
                System.debug('--> MemDocs: ' + md);
            }
            if (memDocId == null) {  // If above related list had no container then create one in that related list.
                Membership_Document__c newMemDoc = new Membership_Document__c();    
                newMemDoc.Document_Type__c = 'Membership Agreement';
                newMemDoc.Name = 'Membership Agreement';

                newMemDoc.Membership_Document__c = accountId;
                insert newMemDoc;
                memDocId = newMemDoc.Id;
            }

            // insert the PDF attachment into the container that was created or found above.
            Attachment attach = new Attachment();
            attach.Body = body;  
            attach.Name = 'MAP - ' + application.Account_Name__c + ' ' + Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') + '.pdf';
            attach.isPrivate = false;
            attach.ParentId = memDocId;
            insert attach;

        }
        System.debug('--> End makePDF');
    }
```

Below is a snippet of the VF page that displays the values. Every value *except*  `application.Shipping_Country__c` & `application.Billing_Country__c` display their updated values, as expected.

```
<apex:page standardController="Membership_Application__c" tabstyle="Account" extensions="VFC_MembershipApplication" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" cache="false">
  <apex:variable var="application" value="{!Membership_Application__c}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="addresses" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Headquarters Address" columns="1" >               
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Shipping_Street__c}"          id="shippingStreet" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Shipping_City__c}"            id="shippingCity"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Shipping_State_Province__c}"  id="shippingState" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Shipping_Zip_Postal_Code__c}" id="shippingPostal"  />
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Shipping_Country__c}"         id="shippingCountry" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Billing Address"  columns="1" >               
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Billing_Street__c}"          id="billingStreet"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Billing_City__c}"            id="billingCity"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Billing_State_Province__c}"  id="billingState"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c}" id="billingPostal" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!application.Billing_Country__c}"         id="billingCountry"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I did not include the entire code from both pages because it's well over 1000 lines.

My concrete questions:

1. Can anyone see anything obvious why the PDF page's address all display correct updated values *except* for the *_Country__c fields?
2. Does anyone know of something that could be happening between the dedug logging and the page generation that would affect this.

(any other ideas also welcome)

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try a debug after the pdf as well, to find out if it's a data problem or a displaying problem? Also; are the countries picklists?

Comment: Yes, the values entering and exiting makePDF are the same (correct & expected).

The values from the original page that created assigned the values are from picklists. I did not realize this might be important?
The page I describe above is MembershipApplicationPDF.vfp . I created this page for PDF generation only because layout changed from MembershipApplication.vfp and displaying checkboxes in the PDF was problematic. The original MembershipApplication.vfp page shows the correct values.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this applies to you, but thought I should share: For country picklists it often happens that the picklist values itself are country codes and those get translated into 'real' country names in the translation (also to english). If you display the picklist in a PDF (with apex:outputfield) it will show the translated value, thus the country name. If you copy the value to another field and display that field, it will show the  country code..

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you have right API name for the Country field you are currently using? If the applicable field changed, maybe this code wasn't updated.

Comment: @Jeremy: I'm beginning to wonder the same given the responses above. If so, however, it points to a fundamental misunderstanding on my end of how everything is getting passed around. Will test a few things and post back with questions. Thank you.

Comment: So it looks like your country fields are all custom fields. Are they derived from the standard address fields? I bet they're being derived from the BillingCountry/ShippingCountry fields, whereas they should be derived from the BillingCountryCode/ShippingCountryCode fields.

Comment: @Carolyn: The Country fields on the application are two letter strings such as US, TW, CN. Two letter format is enforced on Accounts with an update trigger. The initial assignment is: `application.Billing_Country__c=account.BillingCountry`.

Comment: Can someone verify my understanding of how SF calls/uses the code above:
The VF page, MembershipApplicationPDF.vfp, is used by the `pageReference` in `makePDF()`. I know this because `PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/MembershipApplicationPDF');`. The controller code, VFC_MembershipApplication.apxc has a `Membership_Application__c` custom object named `application`.  This particular `application` _must_ be the `application` used by MembershipApplicationPDF.vfp because of the first two lines in MembershipApplicationPDF.vfp above.

Comment: @user3565323, I assumed when you said "The values from the original page that created assigned the values are from picklists," that the org has the State and Country Picklists feature enabled. That's true, right? If so, you should set Billing_Country__c from BillingCountryCode. The Code fields should be the source of truth when S&CP's are enabled. (If you don't have that feature on, then I'm not sure what's going on.)

Comment: @Carolyn: I didn't even know that S&CP existed. I checked and it is *not* turned on. From what I can see it looks like the code I took over does something similar with custom code in its "CountryHelper.apxc" class.

Comment: So looking at this from a different angle:
In my makePDF() class above, the debug statements contain the proper values that I want the VF page to use. 
So, let me ask this question:
Can anyone point me to the correct documentation or explain what the "shell" of a VF page are needed to access the values referenced in makePDF instead of the values it is actually using? More clearly, how do I *force* the VF page to use the values of `application.Shipping_Country__c` & `application.Shipping_Country__c` in makePDF()'s debug statements.